# Instructions/Rules Inside Text Area

Tags: text, contextual-help

I know it is possible to change the "Enter Title Here". But is there’s a function to add text (“how to...”, “simple rules to post...”) inside the post text/input area! Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Add some custom javascript to the admin area, using [`wp_enqueue_script()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#input-id').attr('placeholder', 'Did you try Google first?');
});
```

The [`placeholder` attribute](http://diveintohtml5.org/forms.html#placeholder) does not work in Internet Explorer yet. You could [fall back](http://www.modernizr.com/docs/#input) on a [jQuery placeholder plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/placeholder) if needed.

Comment: Thanks. But no js, I was thinking only in standard WP php methods.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Qtip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip) to write your how to...”, simple rules to post..."
and it will show on hover for each element

```
$("jqueryselector").qtip({
   content: 'I\'m at the top right of my target',
   position: {
      corner: {
         target: 'topRight',
         tooltip: 'bottomLeft'
      }
   }
})
```

Update:

even simpler you can use "[Jquery Form Field Default Value plugin](http://www.jason-palmer.com/2008/08/jquery-plugin-form-field-default-value/)"

[Demo](http://www.jason-palmer.com/demo/jquery-form-defaults/)

Usage:

```
$("#myfield").DefaultValue("My Default Value..");
```

Comment: Not out side, but actually inside the post. Similar to the "Enter Title Here" solution.

Comment: ok then i updated my answer